# CoreLocation enabled in simulator

Tags: swift, core-location

didUpdateLocations is not firing 
- `CLLocationManagerDelegate` was implemented correctly with the viewcontroller as a delegate

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

protocol LocationServiceDelegate {
    func tracingLocation(currentLocation: CLLocation)
    func tracingLocationDidFailWithError(error: NSError)
}

class LocationService: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    static var sharedInstance = LocationService()

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    var currentLocation: CLLocation?
    var delegate: LocationServiceDelegate?
    var paymentVC: PaymentViewController?

    override init() {
        super.init()

        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        guard let locationManager = self.locationManager else {
            return
        }

        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }

        locationManager.distanceFilter = 200

    }

    func startUpdatingLocation() {
        print("Starting Location Updates")
        self.locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func stopUpdatingLocation() {
        print("Stop Location Updates")
        self.locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        guard let location = locations.last else {
            return
        }

        self.currentLocation = location
        updateLocation(currentLocation: location)
    }

    private func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        updateLocationDidFailWithError(error: error as NSError)
    }

    private func updateLocation(currentLocation: CLLocation){
        guard let delegate = self.delegate else {
            return
        }
        delegate.tracingLocation(currentLocation: currentLocation)
    }

    private func updateLocationDidFailWithError(error: NSError) {
        guard let delegate = self.delegate else {
            return
        }
        delegate.tracingLocationDidFailWithError(error: error)
    }
}
```

- this is the extension of the viewcontroller where I implement to custom protocole for corelocation tracking
- I call **startUpdatingLocations()** in viewDidLoad

  ```
  extension PaymentViewController: LocationServiceDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

  func tracingLocation(currentLocation: CLLocation) {
      locationService.currentLocation = currentLocation
  }

  func tracingLocationDidFailWithError(error: NSError) {
      print("Error message: \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }

  func startUpdatingLocations() {
      locationService.locationManager?.delegate = self
      locationService.delegate = self
      locationService.startUpdatingLocation()
  }

  func stopUpdatingLocations() {
      LocationService.sharedInstance.stopUpdatingLocation()
  }
  }
  ```

the `corelocation` tracking is not firing in the simulator. However this is enabled.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GogNi.png)
unfortunately, I have no way to test with a device right now

Comment: simulator is not your real device so it can't update your location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know of to simulate core location tracking on a simulator is by choosing one of the location options available in debug tab of the simulator.

[image]